# Точки в конструкторе java

Tags: java

Есть конструктор

```
public CustomizedComparator(Comparator<T>... comparators) {
        this.comparators = comparators;
    }
```

Вопрос в том, что значат эти три точки в нем?

Comment: `Comparator<T>... comparators` аналогично `Comparator<T>[] comparators`- это обозначение массива

Comment: @MrFylypenko только передавать аргументы можно в конструктор не создавая явно массив, а передавать через запятую произвольное количество аргументов

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это конструктор с переменным числом аргументов типа `Comparator<T>`.

В вашем классе поле `this.comparators` вероятно имеет тип `Comparator<T>[]` - то есть массив компараторов.

Вызывать такой конструктор вы можете, например, такими способами:

`CustomizedComparator();`

`CustomizedComparator(comparator);`

`CustomizedComparator(intCompataror, longComparator, stringComparator);`

и так далее.

По сути это является [синтаксическим сахаром](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80) для передачи массивов в методы/конструкторы.

Answer (score 5):

В *JDK 5* была добавлена новая функциональная возможность, которая упрощает создание методов, принимающих переменное количество аргументов. Эта функциональная возможность получила название `varargs`.

Сокращение термина `variable-length arguments` - аргументы переменной длины.

Метод, который принимает переменное число аргументов, называют методом переменной арности, или просто методом `varargs`.

[For example](https://javadevblog.com/argumenty-peremennoj-dliny-v-java.html)

Answer (score 4):

Спасибо за пояснения и ответы. Попробовал на практике, удобно.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Woman> women = new ArrayList<Woman>();
        women.add(new Woman("Катя", "Катина", 18));
        women.add(new Woman("Маша", "Машина", 21));
        women.add(new Woman("Катя", "Сакина", 5));

        Comparator<Woman> compareByName = new Comparator<Woman>() {
            public int compare(Woman o1, Woman o2) {
                return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
            }
        };

        Comparator<Woman> compareByHeight = new Comparator<Woman>() {
            public int compare(Woman o1, Woman o2) {
                return o1.age - o2.age;
            }
        };

        Comparator<Woman> compareBySurname = new Comparator<Woman>() {
            public int compare(Woman o1, Woman o2) {
                return o1.surname.compareTo(o2.surname);
            }
        };

        //Collections.sort(women, compareByHeight);

        CustomizedComparator<Woman> customizedComparator = new CustomizedComparator<Woman>(compareByName, compareByHeight);
        Collections.sort(women, customizedComparator);
        for (Woman w : women) {
            System.out.println(w.name + " " + w.surname + " " + w.age);
        }
    }

    public static class CustomizedComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
        private Comparator<T>[] comparators;

        public CustomizedComparator(Comparator<T>... comparators) {
            this.comparators = comparators;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < comparators.length; i++) {
                result = comparators[i].compare(o1, o2);
                if (result != 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static class Woman {
        public String name;
        public String surname;
        public int age;

        public Woman(String name, String surname, int age) {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
        }
    }
}
```