# Что означает точка в Java?

Tags: java, синтаксис

Что за имена с точкой в java `printer.accept()`?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Имя с  точкой" - ссылка на метод. Имя - объект, метод - метод, который определен в классе. Не знаю, что вы читали. но в большинстве Java книг это подробно и хорошо разбирается.

Comment: Можно пример синтаксиса?

Comment: Стало лучше, но код лучше выкладывать текстом, а не картинкой. И хорошо бы пояснить, что по Вашему делает `printer.accept()`. Кстати, ответ помог?

Comment: Да, ответ помог. Спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Точка в Java используется в разных местах и имеет разные значения.

1. Обращение к члену класса (методу или полю).

   Например, если есть класс `SomeClass` и у него есть метод `someMethod()` и поле `someField`, то к ним можно обратиться через объект класса: слева от точки — объект, справа — член класса.

   ```
   SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
   obj.someMethod();
   System.out.println(obj.someField);
   ```

   Объект необязательно будет прописан явно, он может быть возвращен полем или методом:

   ```
   obj.someMethod().anotherMethod();
   System.out.println(obj.someField.anotherField);
   ```

   Если член класса — статичный, то к нему можно обратиться через класс, тогда слева от точки — класс, справа — член класса:

   ```
   SomeClass.someMethod();
   System.out.println(SomeClass.someField);
   ```
2. Для разделения имен в иерархии пакетов и между пакетами и классами

   Например, если есть класс `SomeClass` в пакете `com.someaddress`, то к нему можно обратиться так:

   ```
   com.someaddress.SomeClass obj;
   ```

   Или импортировать его:

   ```
   import com.someaddress;

   SomeClass obj;
   ```

   В данном случае слева от точки имя пакета, справа класс, либо имя вложенного пакета.

   См. [Что делает точка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/824917)
3. Синтаксис переменного числа аргументов.

   Три точки обозначают переменное число аргументов в методе:

   ```
   void someMethod(String... args)
   ```

   См. [Точки в конструкторе java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/677311)

Вообще рекомендую почитать хотя бы одну [книгу по Java для начинающих](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java) от начала до конца и выполнить упражнения. Вопросы по самому базовому синтаксису после этого должны отпасть.